# Find words which occur together (not necessarily next to each other) in a block of sentences. The words are the keywords of a dictionary | Python

Tags: python, dictionary, nlp, data-analysis, n-gram

I have a dictionary where the keywords can be any number of words and I am trying to see if I can find in a block of text whether those words are there. I have done the NLP processing with n-grams. I am trying to see if for example most or all of the words of a dictionary keyword would be in the block of text near each other.

e.g.

`dictionary = {'countertop handle piece' : 'ID1234, 'fridge door button' : 'ID1235}`

`text = "the situation in the kitchen where the handle of the countertop piece is broken in not looking very good. Blah blah blah blah. Moreover, we wanted to repair the button which is found on the yellow door of the refrigerator."`

So I am looking to be able to identify the sentences, or maybe block of text that contains most or all of those individual words of the dictionary keywords. This is because as with the example above, someone might not call the fridge a refrigerator, and might also not use all the three worlds of the 'fridge door button' near each other.

I know stemming, and tokenization, as well as the removal of stop words and then applying n-gram matching, would help. However, I think the approach would need to be more complex?

I was told co-occurrence matrix would help as it will find the context of the block of text and assess if the block of text is describing a certain thing. With such a method I would be able to find the sentences where all or most of the words in the dictionary keyword occur together in a given sentence.

If co-occurrence or something similar is the way to go, then how do I go about solving it? Coz I tried to look into it, and I can't see how it can help me and most importantly how to implement it and actually solve the problem.

Any sample code/ example in your answers would be really appreciated as I am not very advanced in Python.

Comment: Hi, perhaps nltk might help https://www.nltk.org/book/ch01.html

Comment: hi, thank you for your comment. Yes I tried this, and I am able to find matches for e.g. sentences that have the n-grams exactly as found. What I am trying to achieve, is to do more like artificial intelligence processing of the text, where I can look for the individual words of the keywords even if they are not mentioned in the text at the same order, or next to each other. I hope this explanation makes this a bit more clear. thank you again